# how to revoke sender url in docusign: getting 404

Tags: url, http-status-code-404, docusignapi, sender

[tried using postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I8gpH.png)

**this one is working good:**
we can request POST with request body- create sender to design template by using the API:
[https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2.1/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/views/sender](https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2.1/accounts/%7BaccountId%7D/envelopes/%7BenvelopeId%7D/views/sender)

**but this one is not working**
we can request DELETE with no request body to same above api - to revoke url used for sender but its reponse is 404

check this docusign documentation
https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/EnvelopeViews/createSender/

we can revoke the Url by making a delete call to the Same API(used to create sender).

Answer (score 1):

DocuSign does not presently support deleting / revoking View Tokens.

The token itself has a lifetime equal to the TTL setting for your account. This setting needs to be set by Customer Support and has a default lifetime of 300 seconds, or 6 minutes -- the full range is between 0 and 999 seconds, so you can expand it to roughly 16 minutes if you choose to.

Comment: In documentation they have Note statement. Please read it. We can revoke using delete call. But what it will revoke. They never mentioned it clearly. Either there documentation is misleading.

Comment: Hi Parvez, To my knowledge we've never supported revoking recipient view tokens. The note property you're referring to is something completely separate -- as you can see with our API reference documentation, we don't support DELETE calls for these tokens: https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/EnvelopeViews.

What documentation are you referring to specifically? https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/EnvelopeViews/createSender/ only supports the POST method.